# One-liner to retrieve path from netstat port

Tags: bash, awk, grep, netstat

I'm looking to create a one liner that, given a port number (2550) uses the returned value from netstat would allow me to then run the resulting output against ps -ef to return  the path of the process in question. I have:

```
ps -ef | grep $(netstat -tonp | grep 2550 | awk '{split($7,a,"/"); print a[1]}')
```

and whilst I know

```
netstat -tonp | grep 2550 | awk '{split($7,a,"/"); print a[1]}'
```

returns the expected resulted, the subsequent grep tells me that there is no such file or directory (but, if I do the ps -ef | grep **) it works just fine... I'm obviously missing something... well, obvious, but I can't see what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like (it takes the first PID/port corresponding, not all):

```
Port=2550;ps -f --pid $( netstat -tonp |  awk -F '[ \t/]+' -v Port=$Port '$0 ~ "([0-9]+[.:]){4}" Port { PID= $7;exit}; END { print PID+0 }' ) | sed 's/^\([^ \t]*[ \t]*\)\{7\}//'
```

the last sed is assuming a ps reply  like this (space are important):

```
usertest  4408  4397  0 09:43 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh -p 22 -X -l usertest 198.198.131.136
```

for every PID and with no ending sed:

```
Port=2550; ps -ef | awk -v PIDs="$( netstat -tonp |  awk -F '[ \t/]+' -v Port=${Port} '$0 ~ (":" Port) { print $7}' )" 'BEGIN{ split( PIDs, aTemp, /\n/); for( PID in aTemp) aPID[ aTemp[PID] ] }; $2 in aPID { sub( /^([^ \t]*[ \t]*){7}/, ""); print}'
```

Comment: I must learn to not avoid using sed! That's a neat solution with good readability to boot. Thanks!

Comment: @AskJarv, this could be done in single `awk` if you could post the output of our command `netstat` one then you could get that kind of solution too.

Comment: I'd be curious if anyone has a method for all processes returned?

Comment: added the multi process listing with no sed at the end. Now it's certainly faster to use a correct netstat option line instead of this looping nested awk

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the pids:

```
<sudo> netstat -tulpen | awk '$4 ~ /:2550$/{sub("/.*","",$NF);print $NF}'
```

You can use `xargs` to pass the pid to `ps`:

```
netstat -tulpen | awk '$4 ~ /:2550$/{sub("/.*","",$NF);print $NF}' | xargs -P 1 ps -o pid,cmd -p
```

Comment: This is the first answer I've found to actually work - thanks

Comment: glad to hear that!